# Linking an iPhone app to a Mysql database can I tell the download size?

Tags: iphone, mysql, sql, download

I have this idea for an iPhone app and the first time the app loads it will download data from a database - i'll link it all together.

The question i have is, could I tell the user of the app something like this, through an alert view or something:

"This is the first time you are using this app and it will need to download the data from a database. This will be about (whatever the size is of all the pictures and information)."
- note that the () should tell the user the size of the content of the database of whatever it is.

Then the user can be warned if they are on a cellular connection that this will happen.

I hope this makes sense and can be done in a way:-)

Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to calculate the download size in advance on your server. Then create a simple web endpoint on your server that contains the download size (in KB, MB, etc).

For example,

```
http://myserver.org/data_download_size
```

returns

```
54234908
```

which is the size in bytes of your download. Then you can retrieve that value from your iPhone app and display it to the user.